# pagination layout in Laravel use Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How to create a **pagination layout in Laravel 9 using Bootstrap 5** like this style.

#### pagination layout

[image]

Comment: what have you done so far? If you want to customize the pagination layout maybe this link will help you: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can publish the pagination views. after that, you can customize it

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

#### resources/views/vendor/pagination/default.blade.php

```html
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <nav>
        <ul class="pagination">
            {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
                <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
                </li>
            @else
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">&lsaquo;</a>
                </li>
            @endif

            {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
            @foreach ($elements as $element)
                {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
                @if (is_string($element))
                    <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span>{{ $element }}</span></li>
                @endif

                {{-- Array Of Links --}}
                @if (is_array($element))
                    @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                        @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                            <li class="active" aria-current="page"><span>{{ $page }}</span></li>
                        @else
                            <li><a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            @endforeach

            {{-- Next Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">&rsaquo;</a>
                </li>
            @else
                <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&rsaquo;</span>
                </li>
            @endif
        </ul>
    </nav>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello I try to answer your question. In laravel 9, maybe you can try this code and implement to your project.

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Paginator::useBootstrap();
    }
```

Or you can see full tutorial in this link [Laravel 9 Pagination Example with Bootstrap Tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/laravel-pagination-example-with-bootstrap-tutorial/)
Thank you

Comment: This is no answer to my question, thank you for your explanation

Comment: Not your place to edit the STYLE of answers.